# Spring @DateTimeFormat malformed

Tags: spring, jackson, jodatime

I am using spring 4.2.1 RELEASE

when i use this expression

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
  public void setModifiedTime(DateTime modifiedTime) {
    this.mod = modifiedTime;
  }
```

I got exception like this.

```
Invalid format: "2015-10-07 12:56:37.0" is malformed at " 12:56:37.0"
```

But strangely, It is OK

```
  public void setModifiedTime(String modifiedTime) {
    this.mod = this.modifiedTime = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parseDateTime(modifiedTime);;
  }
```

why this error occured? Do you have any solutions?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: and I use jackson joda 2.6.x

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet so here is the question - what happens when You use one of the DateTimeFormat.ISO enum as ISO attribute value? (code is from the head, may not compile)

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
  public void setModifiedTime(DateTime modifiedTime) {
    this.mod = modifiedTime;
  }
```

Please check too if Your 'pattern solution' works for plain Date object. From the docs about @DateTimeFormat

> Supports formatting by style pattern, ISO date time pattern, or custom  format pattern string. Can be applied to java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar,  java.long.Long, Joda-Time value types; and as of Spring 4 and JDK 8, to JSR- 310 java.time types too.